# enabling vnc after using virt-install

Tags: virtual-machine, kvm, vnc, qemu

I've created a virtual machine using virt-install with graphics --none. I want to enable vnc. I've tried

```
virsh -c qemu:///system qemu-monitor-command vm171-SC-1 --hmp change vnc :3
```

but it doesn't work

```
virsh -c qemu:///system qemu-monitor-command vm171-SC-1 --hmp info vnc
Server: disabled
```

How can I enable vnc after running virt-install? I don't want to install with vnc enabled (i.e --graphics vnc,listen=0.0.0.0,port=) is not an option because I want it to send its output to the same termnial that I am in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit the VM config with `virsh edit` and add the relevant bit of XML within `<devices>`?

```
<graphics type='vnc' port='-1' autoport='yes' listen='0.0.0.0'/>
```

It should also be possible to replicate this using [virt-xml](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/virt-xml.1.html), something like this:

```
virt-xml --build-xml --graphics vnc,port=-1,autoport=yes,listen=0.0.0.0
```

or

```
virt-xml <yourVMname> --add-device --graphics vnc,port=-1,autoport=yes,listen=0.0.0.0
```

However, it looks like it doesn't support the [`autoport`](https://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html#elementsGraphics) keyword as of version 1.3.2 (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS), so it looks like this part would have to be added separately.

Comment: can it be done without changing the xml? I want to be able to script it.

Comment: Looks like a new tool is required: http://blog.wikichoon.com/2014/03/virt-xml-edit-libvirt-xml-from-command.html?m=1

Comment: Looks like `autoport` doesn't work anymore. Got lucky with `virt-xml pw01p.npf.local --add-device --graphics vnc,port=-1,listen=127.0.0.1,keymap=fr`. Notice that I also specified keymap for VNC.